# Change of variables formula: What happens on the boundary?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, change-of-variable

The (multivariate) Change of Variables Theorem (e.g. Blitzstein & Hwang 2019, Thm 8.1.7) states (loosely) that for a random vector X with continuous pdf $f_X$ and an invertible function $g:A_0\to B_0$, where $A_0$ and $B_0$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the pdf of $Y=g(X)$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}
f_Y(y)\cdot |det(J)|=f_X( g^{-1}(y))
\end{equation*}
where $J$ is the Jacobian of $g$.

Why is this Theorem restricted to functions whose domain $A_0$ is an open set? Can it be extended to include the boundary?

I am facing a random vector $X$ whose support are the non-negative reals and a function $g$ such that $g_i(x)=0$ if and only if $x_i=0$, and would like to have a statement relating $f_Y$ to $f_X$ for *all* non-negative real $X$.

Comment: The Jacobian isn't defined at boundary points.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Would you mind elaborating a bit? Could one not find the derivative with a limit argument, assuming that $g$ has continuous derivatives (which is indeed the case for me)? I am also happy to define $g$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to ensure that derivatives exist - my focus is on the support  of $X$ being restricted to $\mathbb{R}^n_+$.

Comment: I remember there was a generalization in Rene Schilling's "Mesures, integrals and martingales". You need the boundary to be a null set and and an open set around and some conditions for the transformation on this open set.

Comment: Fantastic, that sounds most relevant. Would you like to post it as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: @Koncopd are you referring to Corollary 15.9 in Schelling?

Comment: 16.10 in the second edition.